# PHP and OCI, Populate a drop down menu

Tags: php, html

I want to populate a html drop down menu with a list query from database. I have the following...

```
<?php
$conn = oci_connect(//connection stuff goes here//);
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM COUNTRY WHERE COUNTRY_ID IS NOT NULL");

$result = oci_execute($stid, OCI_DEFAULT);



echo '<select>';

while ($row = oci_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<option value=' . $row['DESCRIPTION'] . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';

?>
```

Something to with the qoute marks on the echo line? Any help here would be great :)

Answer (score 1):

This question has nothing to do with Oracle. Just replace this:

```
echo '<option value=' . $row['DESCRIPTION'] . '</option>';
```

... with this:

```
echo '<option>' . htmlspecialchars($row['DESCRIPTION']) . '</option>';
```

You were basically generating this:

```
<option value=Blah Blah Blah</option>
```

**Edit:** And you forgot about `COUNTRY_ID`! Add it to the `SELECT` statement and use it:

```
echo '<option value="' . htmlspecialchars($row['COUNTRY_ID']) . '">' . htmlspecialchars($row['DESCRIPTION']) . '</option>';
```

Comment: Sorry but this has not fixed it either :( PHP returns no errors but on render drop down is not populated with options :/

Comment: @user1214840 - That's basic debugging we cannot do for you. Get familiar with [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump), [print_r()](http://php.net/print_r) and your browser's "View Source" menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your assumption was right, you have to enclose your description in double quotes and also insert it inside the tags, like this:

```
echo '<option value="' . $row['DESCRIPTION'] . '">'.$row['DESCRIPTION'].'</option>';
```

Comment: You need to use `htmlspecialchars()` when inserting arbitrary strings into HTML.

Comment: Thanks, but still no luck. Drop down menu appears but is not populated with any rows. Something wrong with my query perhaps?